# Executing same BackgroundWorker several times depending on condition?

Tags: vb.net, backgroundworker

I used BackgroundWorker to solve a problem in my winforms application, I wanted to be able to cancel a long-running operation and see results live in ListBox while executing the operation. It works fine except when I want to add a checkbox with additional condition. 
The problem is when I want to run several operation at once. Ex. both XX and YY executing XX first and then start with YY in that order.

```
Private Sub UpdateDB_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnTestAll.Click
       If cbxTestYY.Checked OrElse cbxTesteXX.Checked Then
        SetBusyState(True)

           If cbxTestXX.Checked Then
             bkWorker.RunWorkerAsync(1)
           End If
           If cbxTesteYY.Checked Then
             bkWorker.RunWorkerAsync(2)
           End If
       End If
End Sub


Private Sub bkWorker_DoWork(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs) Handles bkWorker.DoWork
    If bkWorker.CancellationPending Then
         e.Cancel = True
         Exit Sub
      Else
         If e.Argument = 1 Then
            AddItemToListBox("", "XX")
            TestUnits(_XXDimensionUnits, True)
            AddItemToListBox("    Calculating Units     ")
            TestUnits(_XXCalculationUnits, False)
         End If
         If e.Argument = 2 Then
            AddItemToListBox("", "YY")
            TestUnits(_YYCalculationUnits, False)
         End If
      End If
End Sub
```

I know I am trying to run multiple tasks on same backgroundworker which is not allowed, but I dont have any idea how to solve this so it runs in specific order.
Appriciate all help !!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just tell the worker what tests it needs to perform.  Start this with an enumeration that declares the tests:

```
<Flags()> _
Private Enum TestsToPerform
    None   = 0
    TestXX = 1
    TestYY = 2
    TestZZ = 4  '' etc, note the value.  Next are 8, 16, 32, 64 etc.
End Enum
```

And start the tests like this:

```
    Dim tests As TestsToPerform = TestsToPerform.None
    If cbxTestXX.Checked Then tests = tests Or TestsToPerform.TestXX
    If cbxTestYY.Checked Then tests = tests Or TestsToPerform.TestYY
    If cbxTestZZ.Checked Then tests = tests Or TestsToPerform.TestZZ
    If tests <> TestsToPerform.None Then
        SetBusyState(True)
        bkWorker.RunWorkerAsync(tests)
    End If
```

And adjust the code in the worker to test the passed argument for each test:

```
    Dim tests As TestsToPerform = DirectCast(e.Argument, TestsToPerform)
    If tests And TestsToPerform.TestXX Then
        '' do test xx
    End If
    If tests And TestsToPerform.TestYY Then
        '' do test yy
    End If        
    '' etc..
```